# Why does the pipe backward operator not work in this case? F#

Tags: f#

```
let J = (-1.0 * y) .* MatrixMath.log  <| Activation.sigmoid (X * theta)
let J = (-1.0 * y) .* MatrixMath.log  (Activation.sigmoid (X * theta))
```

I have the follow two sets of code with the former giving a compile error saying "This funciton takes too many arguements", but the latter works fine.

I thought the pipe backwards operator's goal is essentially to change the order of evaluation which is what I'm trying to do.

How do I write my expression without using parenthesis?

EDIT:

MatrixMath.log just does this

```
type MatrixMath =
    static member log X = X |> Matrix.map log
    static member log X = X |> Vector.map log
```

Comment: I know you are trying to do Neural Networks in a functional manner. I too am doing the same, but I avoid the use of a functional style until a latter step. Since I am converting Python the process goes, find Python types, convert Python to F# almost line for line not using of piping opertors, get F# to compile, get F# to run, dump python values for comparison, compare python dumped values with F# values and adjust code as necessary, add assertions, then modifiy F# code to be idiomatic F#. It seems slower but is actually faster because it is all verified when done and type correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pipe operator has low precedence. What you try to evaluate is something like this:

```
let J = ((-1.0 * y) .* MatrixMath.log) <| (Activation.sigmoid (X * theta))
```

or a similar atrocity.

If you really need to put backwards pipe in there, try something like this:

```
let J = (-1.0 * y) .* (MatrixMath.log <| Activation.sigmoid <| X * theta)
```

or break it up in two lines:

```
let J = 
    let K = MatrixMath.log <| Activation.sigmoid (X * theta)
    (-1.0 * y) .* K
```

Comment: Ah, okay... I thought it had higher precedence. I just wanted to remove the parenthesis :(

Comment: I would keep the parentheses. One thing that I've learned is to never depend on memorizing operator rules. It's so simple to put it out of picture, so why bother.

Answer (score 3):

In F# `(<|)` operator has left associativity, so your expression is parsed like this:

```
let J = ((-1.0 * y) .* MatrixMath.log) <| Activation.sigmoid (X * theta)
```

If you feel opposed to parentheses, you could possibly rewrite the code like this:

```
(*not tested*)
let flip f a b = f b a
let J = MatrixMath.log <| Activation.sigmoid (X * theta) |> flip (.*) <| -1.0 * y
```

Comment: haha, thanks for the suggestion but I think that makes it worse than parenthesis. But it does make sense now!